# Looping through string - exit on null not zero

Tags: c

I've written a small program to highlight the problem I'm having in C.  I expected that in the following code, the display for loop would print 0, but exit on null; however, the loop exits on 0.  What on earth am I missing / don't I understand?  Your help is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int iArray[] = {1, 2, 0, 4, 5, '\0'};
    int cArray[] = {1, 2, 0, 4, 5, '\0'};

    for(i=0; iArray[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("\nElement: %d", iArray[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; cArray[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("\nElement: %d", iArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, I would advise using a while loop for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Just to expand on everyone else's answer, in C, `'\0' == NULL == 0 == (void *)0`. '\0' is just *a representation* of null. Since C does not allow mixed type arrays, there are different representations of NULL. Hope this helps you understand more clearly that your code is more of a representation issue.

Comment: remember this `0 == '\0'` but `0 != '0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes, you seem to want to create a string of digits. The digit `'1'` is not the same as the character with the value `1`.

Also, your arrays are mysteriously `int`, when they should be `char`.

Try:

```
const char iArray[] = { '1', '2', '0', '4', '5', '\0'};
```

which of course can be simpler written as:

```
const char iArray[] = "12045";
```

Comment: He's using `%d` in the format string, so it might be ints. I think there's a confusion on the `null` terminator idea.

Comment: Thank you (everyone who commented) for your help.  I was being daft and should have used char for the array instead of int, as obviously 0 == '\0' != '0'.

Answer (score 2):

The character literal `'\0'` is actually the same as the integer literal `0`. So it stops when it hits the zero in your arrays.

To be more precise, `'\0'` is the octal value of zero. All character (and of course string) escape sequences with a leading zero are octal values, and will be inserted by the compiler "as is".

---

For arrays there is another way of finding the end, namely to get the the number of items in the array, like in

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(iArray) / sizeof(iArray[0]); i++)
```

However, the trick of using e.g. `sizeof(iArray) / sizeof(iArray[0])` to get the number of items in the array only works on real array. As soon as you pass an array around (e.g. as an argument to a function) it decays to a pointer and the "trick" can no longer be used.

Comment: Just for completeness, `sizeof iArray` is also valid, the `()` is only required when the enclosed token is a typename, e.g. `sizeof (int)`

Answer (score 2):

```
0 == '\0'
```

So the `iArray[i] != '\0'` is the same of `iArray[i] != 0`

And your arrays contain `0` at the third element so the for loop will print only the 2 first elements of each array.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` and `'\0` are equivalent. Actually the first is a number and the second is a char, which is casted (transformed) to int when inserted in the array. Probably you wanted to create a string of characters, so create an array of type `char`, wrap each number in `'0'` quotes and replace `%d` with `%c`.

Note: `'0'` represent the *character* zero, which is different from literal `0` and equivalent `'\0'`, as you can see on [the ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html). Same happens for `1` vs. `'1'`

If you intended an array of integers, then you cannot use `'\0'` as a terminator for the reason stated in the first sentence (unless you are sure 0 will not appear inside the array), keep the length of the array somewhere and use it for iterating.

Comment: One gripe. 0 is not an integer. It is a magic number in decimal representation. It can be short, byte, long, double, whatever.